# Obtaining Value from another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two functions where in one function i am generating a random value and writing it in a

tag . 
Subsequently I want the value generated to be used in another function.

```
   <script>
    function generate()
    {
      var m = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
      alert(m);
      document.getElementById("keys").innerHTML=m+" This is your key";
     return false;

    }

  function a()
  {

    var id= document.getElementById("keys").value;
    alert(id);
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    firebase.database().ref('sample/'+ id ).set(message);
    return false;
 }
 </script>
 <p id="keys" style="font-family:'Lato',sans-serif"></p>
```

Comment: `function generate(){
      return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
    }` and `var x = generate()`

Comment: Please use the preview when writing a question to get the formatting down right before hitting submit. It's very helpful to potential answerers.

Comment: declare your var m outside the function and assign value to in the function.so var m will be globally accessible to you in another function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the generate() function return the random number:

```
function generate()
{
  var m = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
  document.getElementById("keys").innerHTML=m+" This is your key";
  return m;
}
```

Now you can get this random number in another function like:

```
function a(){
  var randomNumber = generate();
}
```

Now you can use the randomNumber variable inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `innerHTML` attribute of the target DOM element but then tried to read the `value` attribute.

Use

```
var str = document.getElementById("keys").innerHTML
```

again to access the stored value. If you are interested in the random number only then you will have to separate it from the rest of the string with

```
var m = str.split(' ')[0];
```